# setting up layered navigation template from catalog.xml

Tags: layout, template, category, layered-navigation

I am trying to set up the root template of `<catalog_category_layered>` from catalog.xml

I know how to use admin to change the root template for categories, but i want to change it from 'catalog.xml'. 
I added

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/product_view_custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

in `<catalog_category_layered>` just after the node starts. But it is not taking that template.

EDIT:
IS the final say which layout is to be loaded for a category page is decided by magento admin? I guess YES.

If YES is there any way i can hard code my required layout to magento. Even if it means editing the core file i don't mind as this is for a internal beta release of an existing website. Why I am trying to do this is if i change anything in Admin it screws the live site

NOTE : The answer below was accepted as my question was slightly different initially. and for that it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and add the template overwrite to your templates `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <catalog_category_layered>
      <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/product_view_custom.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
   </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

**[EDIT]** Zamil pointed out he also requested a way of overwriting the Category layout updates and provided the solution for this. In my opinion this should be done by overwriting the controller from a custom extension but can be done by copying the `CategoryController.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/controllers/` and commenting out the following on line *149*

```
$this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayo‌​ut());
```

Comment: but these updates will not work when u give any layout updates form admin side.any method to override the layout updates given frm admin side using catalog or local xml file?. The actual question i meant to ask was that

Comment: you mean from the layout tab in a category?

Comment: yes.there is layout update from layout tab in category. So site loads that template which is a fair thing when shop owner is concerned.But i cannot do it as i am releasing an internal beta of an existing high traffic website.So is there any way in which i can hard code the template i want in magento? Even if it editing the core files i don't mind.audience are limited to a few 100s

Comment: hm disabling You can probably prevent the layout update from the category layout tab but I wouldn't know how. You should probably check the category view controller if a layout update is performed

Comment: One thing i understood, The layout updates that are coming from the Admin has preference. And @Sander Mangel. please update your answer with this comment out this `$this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());` in `line # 149` in `CategoryController.php` to disable the layout updates coming from admin. please add this in your answer so in future it may help somebody.